# combobox with checkbox within a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I need to display combobox with checkbox option within a DataGrid in WPF. Please provide any solution for that.

I have tried the below code

```
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Template">
                <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox>
                            <ComboBoxItem BindingGroup="{Binding Program}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Width="20" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Program}" Width="100" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It will output like this

[image]

Anyone please help to load collection of items in combobox and to correct my code.

CS code:

```
  private void resultGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var programs = new List<Programs>();
        programs.Add(new Programs("test", false));
        programs.Add(new Programs("test1", false));
        programs.Add(new Programs("test2", true));

        //var grid = sender as DataGrid;
        resultGrid.ItemsSource = programs;
        Combo.ItemsSource = programs;            

    }
```

And the Model:

```
  public class Programs
{
   public Programs(string Program, bool IsChecked)
   {
       this.Program = Program;
       this.IsChecked = IsChecked;
   }

    public string Program { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Finaly got an idea @Sheridan mentioned :

[image]

Comment: why would you want a checkbox INSIDE a combobox?! Will you have multiple boxes? Did you try to set it as the selected in the above case?

Comment: Yes we have multiple checkboxes inside combobox. For Example the programs like test,test1,test2 will need to display in each combobox with checkbox.

Comment: Put checkboxes as ComboboxItem.

Comment: desired is indeed possible in wpf, but your binding shows a single data value instead of a collection for combo-box. share the data classes bound to the datagrid, lets see how you can achieve the desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided a `DataTemplate` to define that your column should render a `ComboBox`, so I'm not really sure why you can't just extend that and provide a `DataTemplate` to define that your `ComboBoxItem`s should render as `Checkbox`es. Try something like this:

```
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Template">
    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Width="20" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Program}" Width="100" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I'll leave you to finish this off.

Comment: If i use this code check box and textblock not added in Combobox

Comment: *If i use this code check box and textblock not added in Combobox*... of course they're not, there is no `ItemsSource Binding` on the `ComboBox`. I *did* say *I'll leave you to finish this off*.

Comment: I have added the Itemsource as you mentioned and updated the result image.